# When to use \hbar or \hslash

Tags: symbols

I noticed, that while using `unicode-math`, both `\hbar` and `\hslash` produce the same output, i.e., always an `\hslash` (actually, the package defines `\def\hbar{\hslash}` on line 2159). However this output is in contrast with many publications, e.g., Wikipedia or `scienceworld.wolfram.com`. In Wolfram Mathematica, text uses `\hbar`, while code uses `\hslash`.

The description in the `unicode-math` package's documentation

> These are symbols with multiple names.

hints towards a misunderstanding by the package authors, because there IS a difference.

So, is there any rule, when to use which symbol. Is this only a matter of taste?

Comment: As a physicist, I'd say it's a sheer matter of taste. It may of course depend on whether the font has both or not.

Comment: What the difference in meaning should be?

Comment: @egreg: As a physicist: I don't know there's a difference in the meaning of `\hslash` and `\hbar` typesetting such that it would result in a significant change of meaning what those symbols represent.

Comment: From your comments, David's answer and the hold of the question, I conclude that this *is* a matter of taste. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unicode-math` maps TeX names to Unicode and Unicode decided that these were just stylistic variants so there is only one slot, U+210F.

That means there is only one glyph in many Unicode fonts as well, although of course a font can offer multiple variant glyphs for the same Unicode slot.

the mappings from the ISO entity sets as used in MathML and HTML have the same issue, ISOAMSO defined

```
planck: /hbar /hslash - Planck's over 2pi
plankv: /hslash - variant Planck's over 2pi
```

and those `&plank;` and `&plankv;` names are valid in HTML, but they both resolve to U+210F.